# Como hacer que esta Query de la tabla hooks de Prestashop no consuma demasiado recursos del servidor / base de datos?

Tags: mysql, prestashop

Mudé un sitio web hecho en Prestashop 1.5.6 de una cuenta de hosting a otra de la misma empresa y empecé a tener problemas de demasiada utilizacion de recursos, al punto de que la empresa deshabilito temporalmente el acceso a Mysql. La cuenta anterior utilizaba otra version de Mysql, no sé si tendra algo que ver.

Una de las querys problemáticas es esta:

```
USER: *********
DB: ********
STATE: Copying to tmp table
TIME: 178
COMMAND: Query
INFO: SELECT h.id_hook, h.name as h_name, title, description, h.position, live_edit, hm.position as hm_position, m.id_module, m.name, active
FROM `ps_hook` h
INNER JOIN `ps_hook_module` hm ON (h.id_hook = hm.id_hook AND hm.id_shop = 1)
INNER JOIN `ps_module` as m ON (m.id_module = hm.id_module)
ORDER BY hm.position
```

La tabla ps_module tiene 124 registros, la ps_hook_module 408, y la ps_hook 148.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puede ser que antes no tenía este problema y ahora consume demasiados recursos?

Comment: Para recibir una mejor respuesta, por favor, edita tu pregunta, agrega la estructura de las tablas en cuestión, incluyendo los indices, claves, triggers, etc. que tengan cada una.

Comment: @Marcos hecho. Estoy buscando mas por el lado de "problemas al mudar prestashop a otro hosting" que por el de la optimizacion de la consulta mysql, porque esa base de datos y esa consulta sql asi como estaban funcionaban bien en el hosting anterior sin ningun tipo de problemas, resulta muy raro que ahora no funcionen será que hay algo mas que no sea la consulta que está mal